# Detect all certain substrings in Python sequence

Tags: python, substring

The code below demonstrates Penney's Game - the probability of one sequence of heads and tails appearing before another. In particular, I wonder about the efficiency of `while not all(i in sequence for i in [pattern1, pattern2]):`, and more globally about coding this optimally in Python. Is this a reasonable attempt in Python, or is the a better more efficient way. The more I think I know about Python, the more I believe there's always a better way!

```
import random

pattern1 = 'TTT'
pattern2 = 'HTT'

pattern1Wins = 0
pattern2Wins = 0

trials = 1000

for _ in range(trials):

    sequence = ''

    while not all(i in sequence for i in [pattern1, pattern2]):
        sequence += random.choice(['H','T'])

    if sequence.endswith(pattern1):
        pattern2Wins += 1
    else:
        pattern1Wins += 1

print pattern1, 'wins =', pattern1Wins
print pattern2, 'wins =', pattern2Wins

print str((max([pattern1Wins, pattern2Wins]) / float(trials) * 100)) + '%'
```

Comment: OK, so whats your question now?

Comment: @Kasra, really my question is, is this a reasonable attempt in Python, or is the a better more efficient way.  The more I think I know about Python, the more I believe there's always a better way!

Comment: So add this comment to your question and make it nice!

Comment: `while not sequence[-3:] in {pattern1,pattern2}` would be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your sequence with three calls to choice originally then just add the last two and a new choice looping until one of the patterns appears:

```
pattern1 = 'TTT'
pattern2 = 'HTT'
trials = 1000
d = {pattern1: 0, pattern2: 0}

for _ in range(trials):
    sequence = random.choice("HT") + random.choice("HT") + random.choice("HT")
    while sequence not in {pattern1, pattern2}:
        sequence = sequence[-2:] + random.choice("HT")
    d[sequence] += 1

print pattern1, 'wins =', d[pattern1]
print pattern2, 'wins =', d[pattern2]
print str((max([d[pattern1], d[pattern2]]) / float(trials) * 100)) + '%'
```

Some timings with random.seed:

```
In [19]: import random
In [20]: random.seed(0)
In [21]: %%timeit
   ....: pattern1 = 'TTT'
   ....: pattern2 = 'HTT'
   ....: trials = 1000
   ....: patterns = {'TTT': 0, 'HTT': 0}
   ....: for _ in range(trials):
   ....:     sequence = ''
   ....:     while True:
   ....:         sequence += random.choice('HT')
   ....:         for pattern in patterns:
   ....:             if sequence.endswith(pattern):
   ....:                 patterns[pattern] += 1
   ....:                 break
   ....:         else:
   ....:             continue
   ....:         break
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.28 ms per loop

In [22]: %%timeit
   ....: pattern1 = 'TTT'
   ....: pattern2 = 'HTT'
   ....: trials = 1000
   ....: d = {pattern1: 0, pattern2: 0}
   ....: for _ in range(trials):
   ....:     sequence = random.choice("HT") + random.choice("HT") + random.choice("HT")
   ....:     while sequence not in {pattern1, pattern2}:
   ....:         sequence = sequence[-2:] + random.choice("HT")
   ....:     d[sequence] += 1
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.95 ms per loop

In [23]: %%timeit
pattern1 = 'TTT'
pattern2 = 'HTT'
pattern1Wins = 0
pattern2Wins = 0
trials = 1000
for _ in range(trials):
    sequence = ''                              
    while True:                                       
        sequence += random.choice('HT')
        if sequence.endswith(pattern1):
            pattern2Wins += 1         
        elif sequence.endswith(pattern2):
            pattern1Wins += 1
        else:
            continue
        break
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.65 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only care about the last three characters being one of two substrings, I would go with something like:

```
sequence = ''
while True:
    sequence += random.choice('HT')
    if sequence.endswith(pattern1):
        pattern2Wins += 1
    elif sequence.endswith(pattern2):
        pattern1Wins += 1
    else:
        continue
    break
```

`endswith` is much more efficient than `in`, because it doesn't check through the whole string for matches (where you *already know there won't be any*).

---

Alternatively, you could factor out `pattern1` and `pattern2` to a dictionary `{pattern: wins}`:

```
patterns = {'TTT': 0, 'HTT': 0}

...

sequence = ''
while True:
    sequence += random.choice('HT')
    for pattern in patterns:
        if sequence.endswith(pattern):
            patterns[pattern] += 1
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

---

Finally, string concatenation with `+` isn't terribly efficient; strings are immutable, so a new string is created each time. Instead, consider putting the results into a list, and checking the last three items of it:

```
sequence = []
while True:
    sequence.append(random.choice('HT'))
    if sequence[-3:] == ['H', 'T', 'T']:
        ...
```